# Why my react native radio button work very slowly when load another component?

Tags: react-native, radio-button, react-functional-component

Below you can see my react native page code. Here I am going to change content when click the radio button named 'x' and 'y'.

```
const Signup = () => { 
        
         const [type, setType] = React.useState('') 
        
        
        
            const data = [
                {
                  label: 'x'
                 },
                 {
                  label: 'y'
                 }
                ];
        
            const radioHandler = (e) => {
    
                let value = e.label;
               if(value==="Orgaization"){
                console.log(value)
                setType(value)
               }
               else{
                console.log(value)
                setType(value)
               }
              
            };
    
            return(
           <View style={styles.container}>
                    
                    <RadioButtonRN
                    style={{padding:0,width: 'auto'}}
                    data={data}
                    selectedBtn={(e) => radioHandler(e)}
     
                   {type==='x' && x()}
                   {type==='y' && y()}
        
                    </View>
        )
    
      const x = ()=>{
        return(//Here some components)
    
      const y = ()=>{
          return(//Here some components)
```

This code work without any error.
But when I going to load x and y components radio button work very slowly how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the console logs

run on real  device
or cancel other tasks for emulator to run fast